# delete button using destructive style and UIAlertAction

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am new to swift and I am working on a contact app. I would like to be able to delete the contact that I have when a user clicks the `delete` button but I am having trouble implementing it. At the moment I have a function that lets me see the `contact` when the user clicks `Show Details` and also has a `cancel button`. But for my delete I want to be able to get rid of whatever I contact I click on. I will paste the code down below.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedContact = contacts[indexPath.row] as? Contact
        let name = selectedContact!.contactName!
        let actionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            //            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditContact", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactController")
                as? ContactsViewController
            controller?.currentContact = selectedContact
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller!, animated: true)
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Contact selected",
                                                message: "Selected row: \(indexPath.row) (\(name))",
            preferredStyle: .alert)

        let actionDelete = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete" ,
                                   style: .destructive,
                                   handler:nil)

        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                         style: .cancel,
                                         handler: nil)
        let actionDetails = UIAlertAction(title: "Show Details",
                                          style: .default,
                                          handler: actionHandler)
        alertController.addAction(actionCancel)
        alertController.addAction(actionDetails)
        alertController.addAction(actionDelete)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide a non-nil handler for your alert's delete button. Start with that.

Comment: would i pass the function that will do the deleting in the handler?

Comment: Yes, you already did something very similar with the Show Details handler and passing `actionHandler`

Comment: You can do the same thing you did for the "Show Details" handler. Though there's no need to define a separate variable for the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for all with/out action as no need to make a var then add it , you can `addAction` with it's handler directly

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style:.destructive, handler: { (action) in 

      contacts.remove(at:indexPath.row) 
      tableView.deleteRows(at:[indexPath],with:.fade)

}))
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedContact = contacts[indexPath.row] as? Contact
    let name = selectedContact!.contactName! 
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Contact selected",
                                            message: "Selected row: \(indexPath.row) (\(name))",
        preferredStyle: .alert)


     alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Show Details", style:.default, handler: { (action) in 

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactController")
            as? ContactsViewController
        controller?.currentContact = selectedContact
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller!, animated: true)

    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style:.destructive, handler: { (action) in 

        contacts.remove(at:indexPath.row) 
        tableView.deleteRows(at:[indexPath],with:.fade)

    }))

    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style:.cancel, handler:nil))  

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: where does this go in the code exactly. I am not sure where to place it.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, what is the different between `.destructive` and `default` style when add the alert action. I try both but seems no different when I delete one item in my collectionView.